# Can git rebase auto do git fetch?

Tags: git

When I pull from remote, then the remote and local repositories are identical, look like the following:

```
A--B--C    remote master

A--B--C    local master
```

After sometime, others pushed to remote, and I have local commits, then they look like the following:

```
A--B--C--D--E remote master

A--B--C--1--2 local master
```

The my project development guide says, when I want to push my commit, I should do:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

I suppose those commands will lead local master to be:

```
A--B--C--D--E--1--2
```

My question is that, is `git fetch` here necessary? Can't `git rebase` auto fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git rebase` can't auto-fetch, but you can do the exact same thing with this instead:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

What this does is basically a `git fetch`, followed by a `git rebase`.  From the [official Linux kernel documentation for `rebase`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html):

> With `--rebase`, it runs `git rebase` instead of `git merge`.